# How to show PDF document in a View and allow the user to manipulate it in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

Here is the situation: I have a PDF documents that have input fields. When the user enters the inputs and push the "Calculate"button(outside the pdf) the "result" field must be calculated. I have a logics that makes the calculations already defined. Simple example in pseudo code:

```
int firstValue = the_first_input_on_the_pdf.Value;
int seconValue = the_secon_input_on_the_pdf.Value;

int result = firstValue + secondValue;

the_result_input_of_the_pdf.Value = result.ToString();
```

Something like that, but I want to keep the formatting of the PDF file. I already have it ready for filling. Just the calculations have to be done. I have been looking for third party libraries and this is what I stopped at: [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/reviews/) and I want to know if this is possible to do with with it or there is a better way.

PS:I need to implement that in a MVC application.

Comment: So you have a PDF with fields and you have a webpage with a button, right? (If its framed in doesn't matter.) You want someone to fill in the PDF fields and then click your webpage button and a PDF is presented that is the same as the initial PDF (or at least looks exactly the same as the initial) but with a result field filled in? Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. It must be the same pdf document but with a result calculated and filled up autimatically. The calculations must be performed server side and then the same pdf document to be returned to the client but with filled up result field.

Comment: Unless you have an explicit requirement to do it exactly this way it really seems like you're taking something that should be easy and making it really, really hard. You have an HTML button which can submit HTML forms but PDFs are not HTML forms nor is HTML even aware of PDFs. The button can also trigger JavaScript but once again, there's no PDF in the ECMAScript standard. Both PDF and HTML have technologies for fields and buttons but there really is no crossover between the two. Do you absolutely need the fields to be in the PDF and/or do you absolutely need the button to be in HTML?

Comment: @ChrisHaas It is not explicitly required but it would be much more convinient for the user of our application. As a matter of fact I decided not to use th iTextSharp because of the license terms. Its license says that using it that way(as an open source) my application that uses it has to be an open source too which is unaccpetable for me in this particular situation.